# Cloudinary upload widget - styling upload preview image (width and height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cloudinary

Well, I'm try to customize the style of Cloudinary Upload Widget:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget

I want to apply the correct css for limit the image/canvas of the image preview during the progress.
Try to upload an image on the above page to see how it works.

During the upload, a preview is displayed:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbpJu.png)

I want to limit the width/height of the above image preview and whole loading bar. How? What's the css selector?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.image_holder` or `.thumbnail_inner` but it's hard to tell, as there's half a dozen elements there. After you opened the image simply rightclick it and select "inspect element" or something similar.

The widget is only changing some elements during actual upload so you should be able to get a proper selector.

Comment: I have add the following css: div.image {height:165px;} div.progress_bar {width:90%;} .thumbnail_inner {height:165px;} ul.thumbnails.clear {height:165px;} div.image_cover {height:165px; padding:0px;} .thumbnail.done {height:165px;} div.image_holder {height:165px;} canvas {height:165px;}, but I achieve to limit only the image, not the bigger gray square. :(

Comment: maybe you mean div.jcrop-holder ?

Comment: I'm still have this problem. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but that widget is quite complex. It depends on using cropping or not, one or multiple images, responsive styling (mobile view). Also they're using scripting to set inline styles, which may be why you can't make it work. I think you should ask them in their support forum.